# Stripe: Can I create a single "1 month free" promo code for multiple products?

Tags: stripe-payments, coupon

I've been reading though the Stripe documentation but can't figure out if it's possible to have a single promotion code for multiple products, to give a 1-month discount, for products which have both monthly and yearly pricing.

Our product setup is like this:

1. Basic tier product

   - Monthly price (upsells to yearly price)
   - Yearly price
2. Plus tier product

   - Monthly price (upsells to yearly price)
   - Yearly price

I’d like to set up a single promotion code to give to customers, to discount the price of one month, regardless of the product they choose and whether they select monthly or yearly billing.

If I set up a 100% discount coupon then I can apply it to both products, but then if the user chooses annual billing, it discounts the price of the entire year (we only want to discount the price of one month).

If we set up fixed-amount discount coupons, then I'd need to create different promotion codes for each product (we only want to give customers a single code).

Maybe this simply isn't possible with Stripe, but it seems like quite a reasonable/common use case, so wanted check.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with a single Stripe coupon. You would need to create at least two different coupons: one for the basic tier product worth one month, and one for the plus tier worth one month.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. What a shame, we'd love to be able to give our clients a "1 month off" code for any of our subscription products.

Comment: This answer appears to not be possible: per the question there are only 2 products, both of which have yearly prices. It is not possible to target a coupon at a price, thus it is not possible to to make "one for the basic tier product worth one month"

Comment: Yeah, this is a real shame. Struggling with the exact same issue.